# How do you generalised the formula of expanded terms $\frac{((50^A)*(((\frac{(50^B)((\frac{(50^C)+1)}{(4)}))+1)}{(4)}))}{(4)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, formal-proofs

I don't know where to start with this, is it proof by induction? I am trying to create a generalised formula for the expanded brackets and prove that it works for any number of nested terms like the above would be

[image].

If I increased the terms for example I make the powers of 50 go ABCDEFG and so on (where A starts from the out side and works inwards) following the pattern of +1 and divide by 4. What is the general formula and how can I prove it? Can you walk me through the steps.

Comment: Could you use math environnement?

Comment: Sorry I am new to this, what is the math enviroment?

Comment: Yes of course https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference :)

Comment: I have to do this tomorrow, this question will be ready for then

Comment: You want to develop what kind of expression concretely ?

Comment: Hi EDX I have corrected the formulas

Comment: Général formula for what? Because how many A B C D E F? What are their values?

Comment: They are arbitrary random integers

Comment: What is the generalised formula of the expanded terms?

Comment: As shown in the picture

Comment: If the number of powers of 50 are increased in the pattern

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{A_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ your sequence of $A$, $B$ , $C$ ...

Let $$ f_n : x\to \dfrac{x^{A_n}+1}{4}$$

$$ g_n: (x,y) \to \dfrac{x^{A_n}y+1}{4} $$

Given the $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Let's call $P_n(x)$ the n-th iteration of your process.

$$ P_1(x)=\dfrac{x^{A_1}+1}{4}=g_1(x,1)$$

$$ P_2(x)=\dfrac{x^{A_1}\left(\dfrac{x^{A_2}+1}{4}\right)+1}{4}=g_1(x,g_2(x,1))$$

$$ P_3(x) = \dfrac{x^{A_1}\dfrac{x^{A_2}\left(\dfrac{x^{A_3}+1}{4}\right)+1}{4}+1}{4}=g_1(x,g_2(x,g_3(x,1))) $$

So

$$ P_n(x)=g_1(x,g_2(x,g_3(x,g_4(..g_n(x,1)))...)$$